# Change background color when aria-valuenow="off"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, slider

I have the following code:

```
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-slider-handle-snapping ui-btn ui-shadow" aria-valuenow="off" style="left:0%">
```

I want to change background color when `aria-valuenow="on"` or `style="left:100%"`. Is it possible?

Comment: It probably is possible, but you'd have figure out a selector specific enough to overwrite the styles that jQuery UI sets on that element.

Comment: Targeting an attribute is straight forward `a.ui-slider-handle[aria-valuenow=on] {color: red}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to wherever you're triggering changing aria-value:

```
if($('.ui-slider').attr('aria-valuenow')=="on"){
  $(body).css("background-color","red");
} else {
  $(body).css("background-color","none");
}
```

I'd recommend using true and false rather than on and off as this is standard practice. It should also allow you to do this instead:

```
if($('.ui-slider').attr('aria-valuenow')){
  $(body).css("background-color","red");
} else {
  $(body).css("background-color","none");
}
```